# Get information about vouchsafe element created by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, captcha

I'm looking at using the [vouchsafe](http://www.vouchsafe.com/demo) widget as a possible replacement for reCAPTCHA on one of my site forms.

The widget injects elements into the DOM, including

```
<a id="vouchsafe-button" class="" href="javascript:void(0)"> ...
<span id="vouchsafe-button-text-top">Click to Validate</span>
```

When the user performs the required action (drawing a line on the generated graphic element), the two lines above change to:

```
<a id="vouchsafe-button" class="vouchsafe-path-data-saved" href="javascript:void(0)"> ...
<span id="vouchsafe-button-text-top">Path Data Saved</span>
```

Vouchsafe itself has some documentation on the PHP usage of the widget, but nothing about the javascript dealing with the client-side challenge and response.

All I want to do at this stage is record the change in class of `#vouchsafe-button` and the change in text of `#vouchsafe-button-text-top`. I've tried writing`$("#vouchsafe-button").attr("class")` and `$("#vouchsafe-button-text-top").text()` to the console log, but the class is reported as `undefined` and the text is reported as an empty string

Comment: So in effect, you need some way of raising an event when the class on that element changes?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Eventually yes (I was thinking of using `.change()` on `#vouchsafe-button` - but my first attempts at that didn't even generate a response entry in the console). However, there didn't seem to be much of a point in looking at the change event until I could get the text and the class from the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer addresses the title of the question (and @RoryMcCrossan's response, which was to guess that my original intention was to raise an event when the element changes), although it doesn't quite answer the question itself.

The vouchsafe plugin widget injects a number of elements into the DOM (including the button link described in my question), several of which change content when the user performs the required action.

As the jQuery `.change` event is not available to non-input elements and hidden input elements - and in the absence of a stable cross-browser observer for mutation events - the only really feasible cross-browser solution is to use `setInterval`, looking for changes in an appropriate element (I chose `#vouchsafe-chellenge-response` which seemed more appropriate than my original choice).

My eventual solution (using the `.load` method to handle any required validation) is:

```
watchforchallenge=setInterval(function(){
    resp = $("#vouchsafe-challenge-response");
    if (resp.val()) {
        $("#unbanresponse").load("/forbidden/functions/unban.php",removecaptcha());
        clearInterval(watchforchallenge);
    }
}, 500);

function removecaptcha(){
    $("a#vouchsafe-button").slideUp();
}
```